# How to sort nested items on field in 'parent' model?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails and try to make the right query. But after reading the documentation and examples I don't manage to get the right query out of it. So I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Situation I build an app where trainers can setup trainings, and give these trainings on several dates (the dates are called thrills), other users can subscribe for these thrills. It has the following structure:

```
class User
  has_many :trainings
  has_many :thrills, through: :trainings
  has_many :reservations

class Training
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :thrills
  has_many :users, through: :thrills

class Thrill
  belongs_to :training
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :users, through: :reservations

class Reservation
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :thrill
  has_one :training, through: :thrill
```

**Question**
How can I make a list of all reservations of the current_user ordered by the thrilldate? The thrilldate is set in the Thrills model.

In my reservations_controller.rb I have:

```
@reservations = current_user.reservations
```

This gives the right list of all the reserations, but I want to sort list this on reservation.thrill.thrilldate
I tried so by using this view:

```
<% @reservations.order("reservation.thrill.thrilldate ASC").each do |reservation| %>
```

Unfortunately this gives the error:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: reservation..thrill.thrilldate: SELECT
>   "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."user_id" =
>   ? ORDER BY reservation.thrill.thrilldate ASC

Who knows how I can refer to the thrilldate in the Thrills model? Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `thrilldate` is a column on `Thrill`

```
@reservations = current_user.reservations.joins(:thrill).order('thrills.thrilldate asc')
```

Comment: Awesome! I was trying to do this in the view, but this works super. Learned a lot, thanks!